# Creating a list of objects and iterating through in C++

Tags: c++, list, class, object, iterator

I am trying to add items(instances of class item) to a list to create a sort of inventory and then have to ability to display the list, however, I cannot get the iterator to work properly, namely in dereferencing it.

```
class gameHandler {
public:
    string playerName;
    player gamePlayer;
    list<item*> listOfItems;
    void gameInit();
    void gameMenu();
    void createPlayer();
    void createItem(string id, list<item*> list);
    void displayItems(list<item*> itemList);
};
void gameHandler::createItem(string id, list<item*> list)
{
    item *newItem = new item(id);
    list.push_back(newItem);
}
void gameHandler::displayItems(list<item*> itemList)
{
    list<item*>::iterator it;
    for (it = itemList.begin(); it != itemList.end(); it++);
    {
        cout << it->id << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(*it)->id`. You have an iterator referring to a pointer; you need yet another level of indirection to get to actual data.

Comment: Note also that `createItem` is a no-op (except that it leaks memory). You are passing `list<item*>` by value; `list` is a temporary object, a copy of the actual argument; it's destroyed soon after you push the item onto it.

Comment: Look up "pass by reference"

Comment: Are  you using C++11?

Comment: Thank you, however, upon changing it to " (*it)->id " I am getting an error saying that the pointer is not dereferencable. I also changed the parameters for createItem() so that I am passing by reference, and left it how it was in the display function so as not to alter the list when called upon (I knew about call by reference, but assumed just as with arrays that they were always assumed to be called by reference).

Comment: And I am using whatever c++ visual studio 2015 uses,  so I'm assuming it's 2015